# Successive macro calls with keys has unexpected output

Tags: macros

when I make two successive calls with macros that have key values (defined using package `keycommand`), I do not get the expected result.

Look at the code below, the macro `\firstmacro` calls `\secondmacro` with the key secondparam. The result that I get is:

[image: codeoutput]

Yes, the result I expected is obviously:

[image]

Here is my "naive" code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{keycommand}

\newkeycommand{\firstmacro}[firstparam]{
    \secondmacro[secondparam=\commandkey{firstparam}]}

\newkeycommand{\secondmacro}[secondparam]{
    The value is \commandkey{secondparam}}

\begin{document}

\secondmacro[secondparam=316] (called with \texttt{\textbackslash secondmacro})

\firstmacro[firstparam=316]  (called with \texttt{\textbackslash firstmacro})

\end{document}
```

(if you could not only give a solution but also explain why this happens it would be great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the reason, but using `\tracingmacros` shows that `316` never appears after `secondparam` in the `log` file, so the value is not really available.

Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{keycommand}

\newkeycommand{\firstmacro}[firstparam]{%
  \edef\ckfirstparam{\commandkey{firstparam}}%
  \secondmacro[secondparam=\ckfirstparam]%
}

\newkeycommand{\secondmacro}[secondparam]{%
  The value is \commandkey{secondparam}%
}

\begin{document}

\secondmacro[secondparam=316] (called with \texttt{\textbackslash secondmacro})

%\tracingmacros=1

\firstmacro[firstparam=316]  (called with \texttt{\textbackslash firstmacro})

%\tracingmacros=0

\end{document}
```

[image]

For general text as the value of `firstparam`, use `\protected@edef`, not `\edef`.

There are better ways for coping with commands taking key-value arguments, for instance `expl3`, but probably a real world use case would be better for finding a good solution.

Comment: To vote you up it is not enough to thank you for the solution: Thanks, I saved a lot of time. Not only the explanations, as I desired, even you considered the case when the parameter is general text, as it is actually the situation in my real case, where I need to input `10 cm` as parameter. God bless you!