# Using letter format as parameter for successive macro calls

Tags: macros

People!

I want to give the letter format, i.e., `\tiny`, as parameter for a macro `\printarray` that calls another macro `\subprintarray`.
With the given code below I expect such a result:

[image]

But I get following:

[image]

I do not why the letter format is lost in the second macro call.
I use the technique of `\protected@edef` that [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) showed me in [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273001/successive-macro-calls-with-keys-has-unexpected-output)

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{keycommand}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newkeycommand{\printarray}[myarray={"a","3.4","more", "Test"},arrayformat={\small}, n=3]
{
    \edef\tagsaux{\commandkey{myarray}};
    \edef\naux{\commandkey{n}};
    \protected@edef\formataux{\commandkey{arrayformat}};

    \subprintarray[submyarray=\tagsaux, subarrayformat={\formataux}, subn=\naux]
}

\newkeycommand{\subprintarray}[submyarray={"a","3.4","$sin(90)+4$"},subarrayformat={\small}, subn=3]
{   
    \protected@edef\subtags{\commandkey{submyarray}};

    \foreach \xpos in {1,2,...,\commandkey{subn}}{
        \path (1.5*\xpos, 1) node { \pgfmathparse{\subtags[\xpos]}\pgfmathresult };
        \path (1.5*\xpos, 0) node { \commandkey{subarrayformat} \pgfmathparse{\subtags[\xpos]}\pgfmathresult };
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\tags{{"ABC","b","$\sin(20)+4$","111","4","5","6","7"}}

Call to \texttt{\textbackslash subprintarray}\\
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \subprintarray[submyarray=\tags,subarrayformat={\small },subn=4]
\end{tikzpicture}}

Call to \texttt{\textbackslash printarray}\\
\fbox{   
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \printarray[myarray=\tags,arrayformat={\tiny}, n=4]
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

I use TikZ-pgf to perform a loop and deal with an array but I don't think that is the problem.

Please do not change the macro calls but modify only inside the macros.
(Explanations to better understand the problem/solution are **pretty** welcome)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\tiny` is a macro that doesn't survive `\protected@edef` and should be prefixed by `\protect` in case it eventually ends up in it.

Comment: @egreg : yes it worked writing `\protect\tiny` as a parameter. Quite practical. Thanks! When I was trying I discovered than `\tiny\normalfont` also works the desire result, although is inelegant. At the end I found Guho's solution, the `\expandafter\noexpand` in the macro code,  the best compromise between practical and elegant. Thanks for your fast answers. My code looks good and it works! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this issue stems from the `\tiny` option being expanded prematurely in your `\protected@edef\formataux{\commandkey{arrayformat}};` line in `\printarray`. Adding `\expandafter\noexpand` before `\command{arrayformat}` to limit the expansion appears to fix it (I end up with your expected result). Adding `\noexpand` in front of `tiny` in the call works as well. I'm guessing this is a byproduct of the approach `keycommand` uses to store the parsed options (`\commandkey{arrayformat}` expands to `\csname keycmd->printarray@arrayformat\endcsname`).

I'd recommend using `pgfkeys` as the behavior is much more intuitive and flexible. Below is your example implemented with `pgfkeys` - macro calls are unmodified, as requested. In it, the options in `\printarray` are parsed and the `arrayformat` is stored directly in `\formataux` (i.e., `\formataux` expands to `\tiny`, as expected):

**Edit:** Thanks to @cfr for pointing out that the `\pgfkeys` can be all defined in a single call and that `\newcommand{\tags}` is a better approach than `\def\tags` (the former will throw an error if `\tags` is already defined):

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{keycommand}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,%
    myarray/.initial={"a","3.4","more", "Test"},
    myarray/.get=\tagsaux,
    myarray/.store in=\tagsaux,
    arrayformat/.initial={\small},
    arrayformat/.get=\formataux,
    arrayformat/.store in=\formataux,
    n/.initial=3,
    n/.get=\naux,
    n/.store in=\naux,
    submyarray/.initial={"a","3.4","$sin(90)+4$"},
    submyarray/.get=\subtagsaux,
    submyarray/.store in=\subtagsaux,
    subarrayformat/.initial={\small},
    subarrayformat/.get=\subformataux,
    subarrayformat/.store in=\subformataux,
    subn/.initial=3,
    subn/.get=\subnaux,
    subn/.store in=\subnaux}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printarray}[1][]{%
    \tikzset{#1}
    \subprintarray[submyarray=\tagsaux,subarrayformat=\formataux,subn=\naux]    
    }
\newcommand{\subprintarray}[1][]{%
    \tikzset{#1}
    \foreach \xpos in {1,2,...,\subnaux}{
        \path (1.5*\xpos, 1) node { \pgfmathparse{\subtagsaux[\xpos]}\pgfmathresult };
        \path (1.5*\xpos, 0) node { \subformataux \pgfmathparse{\subtagsaux[\xpos]}\pgfmathresult };
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tags}{{"ABC","b","$\sin(20)+4$","111","4","5","6","7"}}

Call to \texttt{\textbackslash subprintarray}\\
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \subprintarray[submyarray=\tags,subarrayformat={\small },subn=4]
\end{tikzpicture}}

Call to \texttt{\textbackslash printarray}\\
\fbox{   
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \printarray[myarray=\tags,arrayformat={\tiny }, n=4]
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice example of using arrays in PGF keys (which I find more-or-less incomprehensible in general). Why 2 calls to `\pgfkeys`, though? Couldn't you set all the keys with a single call? It would be better, if possible, to avoid use of `\def` in LaTeX since it does no checking to ensure it is not overwriting a command. Especially since `\tags` seems like just the kind of thing a package might define....

Comment: @cfr: Indeed you can, thanks for the catch. That was left over from the stepwise adaptation to `pgfkeys`. Answer updated.

Comment: @cfr: Another great point. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @guho, @cfr: you really worked out an elegant answer. At the moment I am using the package `keycommand` (which is more for dummies ;-)) but, in the future, I am going to use `\pgfkeys`, it looks great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Some commands don't survive even `\protected@edef` and among them there are the size changing commands, which are not supposed to be in moving arguments (a moving argument is one that's subject to `\protected@edef` or `\protected@write`, usually sectioning commands or captions).

If they are in such moving arguments they must be prefixed by `\protect`.

Here's a different strategy, that avoids `keycommand` with its problems and rather uses `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { lbj/printarray }
 {
  myarray     .code:n      = \clist_set:No \l_lbj_printarray_myarray_clist { #1 },
  arrayformat .tl_set:N    = \l_lbj_printarray_arrayformat_tl,
  n           .int_set:N   = \l_lbj_printarray_n_int,
  myarray     .initial:n   = {"a","3.4","more", "Test"},
  arrayformat .initial:n   = \small,
  n           .initial:n   = 3,
 }
\keys_define:nn { lbj/subprintarray }
 {
  submyarray     .code:n      = \clist_set:No \l_lbj_printarray_submyarray_clist { #1 },
  subarrayformat .tl_set:N    = \l_lbj_printarray_subarrayformat_tl,
  subn           .int_set:N   = \l_lbj_printarray_subn_int,
  submyarray     .initial:n   = {"a","3.4","more", "$\sin(90)+4$"},
  subarrayformat .initial:n   = \small,
  subn           .initial:n   = 3,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printarray}{ O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { lbj/printarray } { #1 }
  \subprintarray[
   submyarray=\l_lbj_printarray_myarray_clist,
   subarrayformat=\l_lbj_printarray_arrayformat_tl,
   subn=\l_lbj_printarray_n_int,
  ]
  \group_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\subprintarray}{ O{} }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { lbj/subprintarray } { #1 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {\l_lbj_printarray_subn_int}
   {
    \path (1.5*##1, 1) node {
      \strut
      \clist_item:Nn \l_lbj_printarray_submyarray_clist { ##1 }
    };
    \path (1.5*##1, 0) node {
      \l_lbj_printarray_subarrayformat_tl \strut
      \clist_item:Nn \l_lbj_printarray_submyarray_clist { ##1 }
    };
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand\tags{"ABC","b","$\sin(20)+4$","111","4","5","6","7"}

Call to \verb|\subprintarray|\\
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \subprintarray[submyarray=\tags,subarrayformat={\small },subn=4]
  \end{tikzpicture}}

Call to \verb|\printarray|\\
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \printarray[myarray=\tags,arrayformat={\tiny}, n=4]
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

The keys are defined in advance and then set by the command with `\keys_set:nn`. You can see that it's easy to pass the values from `\printarray` to `\subprintarray`. Also extracting an item from a clist variable is easier than with `\pgfmathparse`.

Instead of `\foreach` one can use `\int_step_inline:nnnn` that has no special marker; the current value is simply denoted by `#1` (it must be `##1` here because it is inside a definition).

[image]